# Tормозит анимация в браузере safari на ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, html5

Парни, ситуация следующая: 
Есть браузерная игра. Довольно объемная в плане кода javascript, графики и звуков. Вся анимация построена с использованием createjs. В игре использую два канваса одинакового размера один над другим,а между ними кнопки управления(реализованные стандартными элементами button).

Один канвас является основным и на нем происходит большая часть анимации, а второй подключается по мере необходимости, когда анимацию надо показать поверх кнопок.
Изначально размеры канвасов были 970px на 740px. И вся анимация прекрасно работала в десктопных браузерах, а также в хроме и в фаерфоксе на андроиде. Однако в браузере safari на ipad анимация жутко тормозила. Затем я уменьшил размеры канвасов на 30% от начального. И в safari на ipad производительность выросла. А нимация на нижнем слое перестала тормозить. Но когда я задействую второй(верхний) слой для дополнительной анимации то все снова начинает тормозить.

При этом наблюдается забавная ситуация: если браузер свернуть и развернуть снова, то тормоза пропадают и анимация становится плавной и быстрой. А если снова перезагрузить игру то ситуация повторяется. Если кто в курсе причины такого странного поведения, подскажите пожалуйста как бороться с этими тормозами.

П.С.: делать канвасы еще более меньшего размера не могу. Переносить всю анимацию на один канвас тоже достаточно проблематично.